# SSMS query - prompt upon data insert?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a csv file which gets inserted into a database table A once a year. The csv file cannot be modified. However upon insert, I want an additional column to be created in table A, to be populated by a year i.e 2018 (or 2017 if it was being ran retrospectively). I would like the user to have control over which year is entered. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How is the data inserted? Does the user run an application? From the question title and tags it looks like the user loads a script into SSMS and runs it? So... can they not just edit a variable in the script to change the year that gets inserted?

Comment: Without some kinda application to control the experience it'll be quite difficult to pull this off. As MarcE says, putting a variable at the top of the script would be the simplest way, with some handling for 'this year has already been done, rollback and alert'. Thinking cynically though, do you really want the 'human gibberish' that could make it's way into that prompt? ;)